# the given path format is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2015

the given path format is not supported. help please

```
x.OutputFormat = SautinSoft.ExcelToPdf.eOutputFormat.Docx;
x.ConvertFile(@"‪‪‪C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\Bin\a.xlsx",@"C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\Bin\a.doc");
```

Comment: Perhaps it wants an extension of ".docx" instead of ".doc".

Comment: it didnot work :(